# comma separated stream into struct

Tags: c++, file-io, struct, io, stream

I have a structure with an int and two strings. When reading in the file it is comma seperated for the first two values and the last value is terminated by a newline. The third argument could be empty however.

ex data:  7, john doe, 123-456-7891 123 fake st.

I want to make it so that my program will grab the first number and put it in the int, find the comma and put the second number in the struct's string etc.

First question is should I use a class instead? I have seen the `getline(stream, myString, ',');` but my arguments are different data types so I can't just throw them all into a vector.

my code:

```
struct Person{
    int id;//dont care if this is unique 
    string name;
    string extraInfo;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    assert( argc ==2 && "Invalid number of command line arguments");
    ifstream inputFile (argv[1]);
    assert( inputFile.is_open() && "Unable to open file");
}
```

What is the best way of storing this information and retrieving it from a file that is comma separated for the first two and ends with a newline? I also want the program to ignore blank lines in the file.

Comment: Is the data in CSV format, or just your own encoding where the double quotes around the string values are guaranteed?  (In CSV they wouldn't be needed in certain cases such as should someone only use one name e.g. Madonna).

Comment: quotes are never there, bad habit I guess. Removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd read the file line-by-line using normal `getline()`. Then, put it into a `stringstream` for further parsing or use `string`'s `find()` functions to split the text manually.

Some more notes:

- I don't understand your first question about using a class. If you mean for `Person`, then the answer is that it doesn't matter.
- Using assert for something you don't have control over is wrong, like argc. This should only be used to verify that you didn't make a programming error. Also, if you #define NDEBUG, the asserts are all gone, so they shouldn't really be part of your program logic. Throw std::runtime_error("failed to open file") instead.
- You probably don't want the double quotes in your strings. Also, you might want `"a,b"` to not be split by the comma. Make sure you have tests that assert the required functionality.

Comment: 1- I thought a class might have some difference.2-my program should always have 2 command line arguements at all times. 3- I didn't mean to put in the quotes, I took them out.

Comment: I understand that it should have two parameters, but it's not something you have control over with the program code, you can only verify that it's called correctly. `assert()` is intended to catch programming errors, so it's inappropriate for runtime checks. Your use isn't wrong, it's just against convention and sending the wrong implicit message.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `getline` approach for tokenising a line, but you first have to read the line:

```
vector<Person> people;
string line;
int lineNum = 0;

while( getline(inputFile, line) )
{
    istringstream iss(line);
    lineNum++;

    // Try to extract person data from the line.  If successful, ok will be true.
    Person p;
    bool ok = false;

    do {
        string val;
        if( !getline(iss, val, ',') ) break;
        p.id = strtol( val.c_str(), NULL, 10 );

        if( !getline(iss, p.name, ',') ) break;
        if( !getline(iss, p.extraInfo, ',') ) break;

        // Now you can trim the name and extraInfo strings to remove spaces and quotes
        //[todo]

        ok = true;
    } while(false);

    // If all is well, add the person to our people-vector.
    if( ok ) {
        people.push_back(p);
    } else {
        cout << "Failed to parse line " << lineNum << ": " << line << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of lineNum?

Comment: Line number.  Dunno about you, I just have this habit of counting lines so that when I get an error, I can output which line it happened on.  You'll see I use it at the bottom in case of an error.  Be aware that this code doesn't handle quotes etc.  For that, you'd be better off making a quick function that pulls a single quoted or unquoted string out of the stream (so you don't break at the wrong comma).

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the line in string using getline, use strtok.

```
char myline[] = "7, john doe, 123-456-7891 123 fake st.";
char tokens = strtok(myline, ",");
while(tokens)
{
    //store tokens in your struct values here
}
```

You'll need to include `#include <string.h>` to use strtok